# get list of public predicates defined in a module

Tags: prolog, yap

I know that in Prolog every file defining a module should start with the instruction

```
:- module(module_name, [pred1/arity, ...]).
```

How can I retrieve the list of public predicates exported by a module at runtime?

SOLVED.

?- all(X, [module]:current_predicate(X),CX).

Comment: You should submit the answer yourself and then accept it. And format it properly (four leading spaces).

Comment: The same question popped here some days ago. Note that hen using Prolog compilers such as SWI-Prolog and (maybe also YAP), the module/2 directive may preceded by an encoding/1 directive (which, when present, should be the first term in the first line of the file).